# increment in asp.net mvc razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display incremental values at the first column of following code inside Sr. No. column in ASP.net MVC Razor view. I am doing following but its not working. It showing  0++; only in that column. what wrong I am doing.

```
 @{int i = 0;}

 <table class="table">
 <tr>
    <th>Sr No.</th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModifiedDate)
    </th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>@i++;</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CurrencyCode }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CurrencyCode }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CurrencyCode })
        </td>
    </tr>
 }
```

Comment: <span>i++;</span>, remove the @

Comment: `<span>@(i++)</span>` (you need the surrounding parenthesis)

Comment: `<span>@i</span>
     i++;`

Comment: Without the parenthesis, `@i` and `++` are not treated as a single expression. The value of `i` is output and `'++'` is taken as text literal to be output.

Comment: @(++i) this works for me but all three are correct answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In razor syntax you should create C# scope for C# logical statemens. Can you try the the code below;

```
<td>
    <span>@(i++)</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use like this.

```
         <td>
            <span>@i++;</span>
        </td>
```

you need to write your code as like :

```
         <td>
            <span>@i</span>
        </td>
```

You need to increase value of `i` after `<tr>` tag.
I have given solution with your code.

```
                              @{
                                   var i = 1; @*sr no will start from 1*@
                                }
                                <table class="table">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Sr No.</th>
                                        <th>
                                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModifiedDate)
                                        </th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>

                                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <span>@i</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedDate)
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CurrencyCode }) |
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CurrencyCode }) |
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CurrencyCode })
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        i++;
                                    }
```

Hope it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@{int i = 0;}

     <table class="table">
     <tr>
        <th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModifiedDate)
        </th>
        <th></th>
     </tr>

     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>@(++i)</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CurrencyCode }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CurrencyCode }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CurrencyCode })
            </td>
        </tr>
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

As per @Stephen Muecke suggested you can use:

```
<span>@(i++)</span>
```

Or you can use like this:

```
<span>@i</span> 
 i++;
```

Comment: this `<span>@(i++)</span>`  works but this `<span>@i</span> i++;`
 not